# How to obtain all possible combinations?

Tags: combinatorics

I have a set with $k$ people. I also have $n$ subsets. I need to divide these $k$ people into these $n$ subsets. The maximum sizes of each subset can be different from one another. If $k$, $n$, and the maximum sizes of each subset are known, how can I find out each possible distribution of people into these subsets? $k$ can be larger than, equal, or smaller than the sum of the maximum sizes of all the subsets.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Thoughts ? Attempts ? [MathJaX](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) ? Source ?

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfect scenario for using a generating function.

Let the maximum sizes of each subset be denoted as $m_i$.

Construct the polynomial $(1+x+x^2..x^{m_1})(1+x+x^2...x^{m_2})...(1+x+x^2...x^{m_n})$.

Upon expansion, the coefficient of $x^k$ is the number of ways to partition the people as described in your question.

Comment: it is because you can have anywhere from $0$ to $m_1$ people in each subset. if you want too add the restriction that at least 1 person must be in each subset, just remove the $1$ from each factor.